# NetSuite get GL impact records/lines from Expense Report

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Using Saved Search or SuiteScript, how could I get GL Impact lines which has Account, Amount (Debit), Amount(Credit), Posting, Memo, ... columns.

When I check record schema, I can see there is no such sublist.

[Here is a screenshot for GL impact line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCWrY.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no sublist because the GL lines display is just an extract of the account and debit/credit amounts that are on the transaction lines.

The simplest form of a custom GL lines search includes these from the Advanced search on transactions:

Criteria: Voided = No; Closed = No;

Results:
Account, Amount (Debit), Amount (Credit)

for results you probably also want
Document Number, Memo, Custom GL, Custom Script and whatever of Dept, Location, or Class that are used in your account.